# Добавление CASE в SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select
ag.name as aag_name,
ar.replica_server_name,
d.name as [database_name],
hars.is_local,
hars.synchronization_state_desc as synchronization_state,
hars.synchronization_health_desc as synchronization_health,
hars.database_state_desc as db_state,
hars.last_commit_time
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states as hars
   join sys.availability_replicas as ar
on hars.replica_id = ar.replica_id
   join sys.availability_groups as ag
on ag.group_id = hars.group_id
   join sys.databases as d
on d.group_database_id = hars.group_database_id
   order by aag_name, replica_server_name
```

Не получается сделать замену текста в поле database_state_desc оно же db_state
В отдельном SELECT также не получается сделать реакцию на NULL значение:

```
SELECT 
CASE  database_state_desc 
WHEN 'ONLINE' then 'Primary'
end
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states
```

Comment: *Не получается сделать замену текста в поле database_state_desc оно же db_state* Есть ПОЛНАЯ таблица (или список) значений поля и того, на что они заменяются?

Comment: Разобрался, остался 1 единственный вопрос WHEN 'ONLINE' then 'Primary' работает, там есть значение NULL при попытке переименовать его в "Secondary". Не is null, не null, не 'NULL' не реагирует is - выдает ошибку

Comment: `CASE database_state_desc WHEN 'Online' THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary' END` Ну или привлечь COALESCE() (либо ISNULL), и заменять Null на нечто весьма оригинальное (а хоть бы и то же 'Secondary')

Comment: Если кроме ONLINE и NULL ничего больше нет, используйте ELSE. Иначе, другую форму оператора CASE.

Comment: Спасибо, это одно из решений. Но неужели нельзя заменить именно NULL

Comment: Как же нельзя, все можно, CASE WHEN [database_state_desc] = 'Online' THEN 'Primary' WHEN [database_state_desc] IS NULL THEN 'ВАШЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ' ELSE [database_state_desc] END

Comment: Так вот тут и загвоздка, что в данном случае пишет Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
Решено было использовать другое поле Is_local содержащие 1 или 0 и брать по этому условию

Comment: Это вы с синтаксисом напутали скорее всего написав `CASE database_state_desc WHEN 'Online' THEN 'Primary' WHEN IS NULL THEN ...` вместо `CASE WHEN database_state_desc = 'Online' THEN 'Primary' WHEN database_state_desc IS NULL THEN ...` (см. разницу в синтаксисе [СASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#a-using-a-select-statement-with-a-simple-case-expression), примеры А и Б).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, итоговый вариант:

```
select
ag.name as aag_name,
ar.replica_server_name,
d.name as [database_name],
hars.is_local,
hars.synchronization_state_desc as synchronization_state,
hars.synchronization_health_desc as synchronization_health,
hars.last_commit_time,
 CASE  is_local
  WHEN 1 then 'Primary'
  WHEN 0 then 'Secondary'
 end
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states as hars
 join sys.availability_replicas as ar
on hars.replica_id = ar.replica_id
 join sys.availability_groups as ag
on ag.group_id = hars.group_id
 join sys.databases as d
on d.group_database_id = hars.group_database_id
order by aag_name, replica_server_name
```